# Comparing the lengths of two lists. Why are they different?

Tags: python, csv

I'm tyring to see the numbers of elements in two lists.

*list01* is the list of mnist.csv, read by the readlines() function.

```
list01_file = open("mnist.csv", 'r')
list01 = list01_file.readlines()
list01_file.close()
```

mnist.csv concists of 100 lines each line of which is composed of 785 values.
For example, the first two lines of mnist.csv is like the below.

```
5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,18,18,18,126,136,175,26,166,255,247,127,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,30,36,94,154,170,253,253,253,253,253,225,172,253,242,195,64,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,49,238,253,253,253,253,253,253,253,253,251,93,82,82,56,39,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,18,219,253,253,253,253,253,198,182,247,241,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,80,156,107,253,253,205,11,0,43,154,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,14,1,154,253,90,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,139,253,190,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,190,253,70,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,35,241,225,160,108,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,81,240,253,253,119,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,45,186,253,253,150,27,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,93,252,253,187,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,249,253,249,64,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,46,130,183,253,253,207,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,39,148,229,253,253,253,250,182,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,114,221,253,253,253,253,201,78,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,66,213,253,253,253,253,198,81,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,18,171,219,253,253,253,253,195,80,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,55,172,226,253,253,253,253,244,133,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,136,253,253,253,212,135,132,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,51,159,253,159,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,48,238,252,252,252,237,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,54,227,253,252,239,233,252,57,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,60,224,252,253,252,202,84,252,253,122,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,163,252,252,252,253,252,252,96,189,253,167,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,51,238,253,253,190,114,253,228,47,79,255,168,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,48,238,252,252,179,12,75,121,21,0,0,253,243,50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,38,165,253,233,208,84,0,0,0,0,0,0,253,252,165,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,178,252,240,71,19,28,0,0,0,0,0,0,253,252,195,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,57,252,252,63,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,253,252,195,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,198,253,190,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,253,196,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,76,246,252,112,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,253,252,148,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,85,252,230,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,135,253,186,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,85,252,223,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,131,252,225,71,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,85,252,145,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,48,165,252,173,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,86,253,225,0,0,0,0,0,0,114,238,253,162,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,85,252,249,146,48,29,85,178,225,253,223,167,56,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,85,252,252,252,229,215,252,252,252,196,130,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,28,199,252,252,253,252,252,233,145,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25,128,252,253,252,141,37,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Now I have made *list02* by copy and past, using the first line of mnist.csv, and checked the number of elements by the len() function.

```
>>> list02 = [5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,18,18,18,126,136,175,26,166,255,247,127,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,30,36,94,154,170,253,253,253,253,253,225,172,253,242,195,64,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,49,238,253,253,253,253,253,253,253,253,251,93,82,82,56,39,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,18,219,253,253,253,253,253,198,182,247,241,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,80,156,107,253,253,205,11,0,43,154,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,14,1,154,253,90,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,139,253,190,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,190,253,70,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,35,241,225,160,108,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,81,240,253,253,119,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,45,186,253,253,150,27,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,93,252,253,187,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,249,253,249,64,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,46,130,183,253,253,207,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,39,148,229,253,253,253,250,182,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,114,221,253,253,253,253,201,78,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,66,213,253,253,253,253,198,81,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,18,171,219,253,253,253,253,195,80,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,55,172,226,253,253,253,253,244,133,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,136,253,253,253,212,135,132,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
>>> len(list02)
785
```

However, if I check the number of elements of the first element of *list01*, I get a different number.

```
>>> len(list01[0])
1846
```

I don't understand why it prints out the different number. I think the length of list01[0] shuold be the same as the length of list02, the first line of mnist.csv. Am I thinking of something wrong? Or did I make mistakes while doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list02` is a list of integers.  `list01` is a list of strings.  I bet that, if you check, 1846 is the (character!) length of the *string*:

```
"5,0,0, etc etc etc"
```

Comment: you might want to show an example using `len` on a string and list, I'm not sure what `"5,0,0, etc etc etc"` is suppose to be..

Comment: You can, if you like.  I think it's quite obviously the first line of the `.csv` file, as shown in OP's question.

Comment: It's a string! len(list01[0].split(',')) shows 785! Thank you for your answer! Have a nice day!